# JSR-303 / Spring MVC - validate conditionally using groups

Tags: java, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I worked out a concept to conditionally validate using JSR 303 groups. "Conditionally" means that I have some fields which are only relevant if another field has a specific value.

Example: There is an option to select whether to register as a person or as a company. When selecting company, the user has to fill a field containing the name of the company.

Now I thought I use groups for that:

```
  class RegisterForm
  {
     public interface BasicCheck {}
     public interface UserCheck {}
     public interface CompanyCheck {}

     @NotNull(groups = BasicCheck.class)
     private Boolean isCompany

     @NotNull(groups = UserCheck.class)
     private String firstName;

     @NotNull(groups = UserCheck.class)
     private String lastName;

     @NotNull(groups = CompanyCheck.class)
     private String companyName;

     // getters / setters ...
  }
```

In my controller, I validate step by step depending on the respective selection:

```
  @Autowired
  SmartValidator validator;

  public void onRequest(@ModelAttribute("registerForm") RegisterForm registerForm, BindingResult result)
  {
     validator.validate(registerForm, result, RegisterForm.BasicCheck.class);
     if (result.hasErrors()
        return;
     // basic check successful => we can process fields which are covered by this check
     if (registerForm.getIsCompany())
     {
        validator.validate(registerForm, result, RegisterForm.CompanyCheck.class)
     }
     else
     {
        validator.validate(registerForm, result, RegisterForm.UserCheck.class);
     }
     if (!result.hasErrors())
     {
        // process registration
     }
  }
```

I only want to validate what must be validated. If the user selects "company" fills a field with invalid content and then switches back to "user", the invalid company related content must be ignored by the validator. A solution would be to clear those fields using Javascript, but I also want my forms to work with javascript disabled. This is why I totally like the approach shown above.

But Spring breaks this idea due to data binding. Before validation starts, Spring binds the data to registerForm. It adds error to `result` if, for instance, types are incompatible (expected int-value, but user filled the form with letters). This is a problem as these errors are shown in the JSP-view by `<form:errors />` tags

Now I found a way to prevent Spring from adding those errors to the binding result by implementing a custom `BindingErrorProcessor`. If a field contains `null` I know that there was a validation error. In my concept `null` is not allowed - every field gets annotated with `@NotNull` plus the respective validation group.

As I am new to Spring and JSR-303 I wonder, whether I am totally on the wrong path. The fact that I have to implement a couple of things on my own makes me uncertain. Is this a clean solution? Is there a better solution for the same problem, as I think this is a common problem?

**EDIT**

Please see my answer here if you are interested in my solution in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30500985/395879

Comment: Did you finally find a proper solution for this?
I have a similar issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467124/spring-mvc-and-validate-perform-validate-only-on-specific-condition-or-if-user),
where I need to validate the nested object only if the user entered a value to any of the fields of the nested object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that Spring MVC is a bit picky in this regard,and it is a common problem. But there are work-arounds:

- Make all your backing fields strings, and do number/date etc conversions and null checks manually.
- Use JavaScript to set fields to null when they become irrelevant.
- Use JavaScript to validate fields when they are entered. This will fix almost all of your problems.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I came upon it looking for an answer for a different situation.

I think for your situation you could use inheritance for the forms and then use two controller methods:

The forms would look like this:

```
public class RegistrationForm
{
    // Common fields go here.
}

public class UserRegistrationForm
    extends RegistrationForm
{
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    // getters / setters ...
}

public class CompanyRegistrationForm
    extends RegistrationForm
{
    @NotNull
    private String companyName;

    // getters / setters ...
}
```

The controller methods would look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "isCompany=false")
public void onRequest(
        @ModelAttribute("registerForm") @Valid UserRegistrationForm form,
        BindingResult result)
{
    if (!result.hasErrors())
    {
        // process registration
    }
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "isCompany=true")
public void onRequest(
        @ModelAttribute("registerForm") @Valid CompanyRegistrationForm form,
        BindingResult result)
{
    if (!result.hasErrors())
    {
        // process registration
    }
}
```

Notice that the `@RequestMapping` annotations include a `params` attribute so the value of the `isCompany` parameter determines which method is called.

Also notice that the `@Valid` annotation is place on the `form` parameter.

Finally, no groups are needed in this case.